# Why is Firebase Auth userChanges() not called when Display Name is updated - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-streambuilder

My app has and `AuthGate()` that either sends a user to the `SignInScreen()`, the `UpdatesNeededScreen()`, or the `FloatingTabBarView()`, depending on the current users data. If the email, pictureURL, or displayName are null, the `UpdatesNeededScreen()` is shown and there's a `ListView` in that screen showing which info needs to be added. When a user adds their email or name I also use `user.reload()` at the end of those functions just to make sure the `AuthGate()` reloads the user data and the user is sent back to the `UpdatesNeededScreen()` if more info is missing or to the `FloatingTabBarView()` if that was the last thing needed. This works perfectly with the email but when the name is added the `AuthGate()` never updates. If I close the app after that and reopen it, the new display name is there, but that's not being recognized when it's actually updated. Does anyone know why?

`AuthGate()`:

```
class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(), initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser, builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // User is not signed in
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('sign in');
          }
          return const SignInScreen();
        }

        final User user = snapshot.data!;
        if (user.email == null || user.photoURL == null || user.displayName == null) {
          // Show edit profile screen
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('edit profile');
          }

          List infoNeeded = [];

          if (user.email == null) {
            infoNeeded.add('email');
          }
          if (user.photoURL == null) {
            infoNeeded.add('photoURL');
          }
          if (user.displayName == null) {
            infoNeeded.add('displayName');
          }

          return UpdatesNeededScreen(infoNeeded: infoNeeded);
        }

        // All good
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('signed in AND all info given');
        }
        return const FloatingTabBarView();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Function to save the display name:

```
  void saveChanges() {
    if (_nameFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _nameFormKey.currentState!.save();

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

      try {
        user.updateDisplayName(_nameController.text).then((value) {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(
              {'displayName': _nameController.text},
              SetOptions(merge: true)).then((nn) {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
            });

            user.reload();
          });
        });
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(e.message);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. If I slid back to the `UpdatesNeededScreen()` it was correct and didn't ask for the name anymore. `The StreamBuilder()` was updating but since I was pushing different screens to update info, I needed to put `Navigator.of(context).pop()` at the end of the function.